# how to add dynamically windowMS and max value in rateLimit using express-rate-limit

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, rate-limiting, express-rate-limit

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const limitMiddleware = (req = {}, res = {}, next) => {
    return rateLimit({
        windowMs: req.body.timeLimit,
        max: req.body.messageLimit,
        keyGenerator: function (req) {
            console.log("req.query.userId", req.query.userId);
            return req.query.userId;
        },
        handler: function (req, res, next) {
            res.status(429).json({
                message: "You have exceeded your request limit.",
            });
        },
        headers: true,
    });
};

module.exports = limitMiddleware;
```

i tried with set the limit and duration that are get in body parameter but it's not send message when limit exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. express-rate-limit does not currently support dynamic window sizes. `windowMs` must be a single number that is the same for all requests.
2. The `rateLimit` instance must be created before you handle any requests. Your code will create a new instance for every request, but never use any of the instances.

Also, one third related problem, the `max` field *can* be dynamic, but it should be a function, similar to your `keyGenerator` to work correctly.

---

Disclosure: I'm the author of express-rate-limit.